# simple question about port 80 on ec2 virtual Windows Server

Tags: glassfish, windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2

I set up a Windows 2008 Server virtual machine on Amazon ec2.  I gave it a "security group" that includes HTTP 80.

I installed GlassFish server and have it listening on port 80.

I can Remote Desktop to the machine (ec2-174-129-128-105.compute-1.amazonaws.com), open a browser, and browse to "http://localhost:80" and see the GlassFish welcome page.

However, when I attempt to browse to the machine from my local laptop like so ...

http://ec2-174-129-128-105.compute-1.amazonaws.com:80

... it just times out.

Any idea what I have to do to open the machine to browsing from the internet?  Or what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.  I had to open port 80 on the windows firewall.  It turns out Windows Server 2008 is locked down excessively tightly out of the box.

Comment: I wouldn't say "excessively". That's how all servers should be. You start by blocking all ports and only unblock the ones specific to the services you want to expose... i.e. whitelist not blacklist.

Comment: Yes, I suppose Servers should be locked down out of the box.  Port 80 should not be open by default.  However, it was surprisingly frustrating that I couldn't use IE to browse/download things until I figured out how to deactivating that safety "feature" -- I think that's where my "excessive" comment came from. :)

Answer (score 0):

try to give the ip address of the machine instead of

http://{your ip address}:80

and see if it works

Comment: No, using the IP address didn't work either.  FYI, I can RDP to the virtual machine fine using the name.